# "ld: library not found for -lblacsF77init"

Tags: makefile, mpi, scalapack

I am trying to compile my code using mpi on my macbook but I get the following error:
"ld: library not found for -lblacsF77init". I don't understand where I can find this library and how to create a correct path.

This is the makefile: # serial Fortran compiler program

```
    F90 = gfortran -I/usr/local/include
       # parallel Fortran compiler program
       MPIF90 = /usr/local/bin/mpif90.
       # Compiler flags
       F90FLAGS =
       CFLAGS = -x f95-cpp-input.
       # LDFLAGS are the linker flags
       LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
       F77LIBS =.
       MATLIB = -framework Accelerate
       hsl = /usr/local/opt/scalapack/
       hb = /usr/local/opt/openblas/
       hompi = /usr/local/lib/openmpi/
       MPIMATLIB = -L$(hb) -L$(hsl) -lscalapack -L$(hsl) -lblacsF77init -
lblacs -lblacsF77init -L$(hompi) -Wl,-framework,vecLib
```

Thank you very much for any help you may provide.

Comment: It looks as if you are on Mac OSX. How did you install scalapack?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a macbook running OSX, you don't need to build scalapack:

```
brew install scalapack gcc
```